# closing jquery-ui dialog box with parent ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way of getting the id of my parent div without having to append the "#" in front like I do below?

Thanks

```
var parentDivId = $(div).closest("div").attr("id");
$("#" + parentDivId).dialog('close');
```

this closes the dialog box:

```
$("#" + parentDivId).dialog('close');
```

this doesn't work:

```
$(parentDivId).dialog('close');
```

Comment: You already have parent div, why do you want it's id? `$(div).closest("div").dialog("close");`

Comment: what is $(div); is it a variable? if not, you probably need a selector in there. ie $('.myclass').closest. . .

Comment: if `div` is a div, doing `$(div).closest('div')` is redundant because `div` IS a `div` and `.closest` will return the current selected element if it matches the selector rather than going to a parent. Can you please clarify what is contained in `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `parentDivId` is enough to get it done, try the below one:

```
$('[id="' + parentDivId + '"]').dialog('close');
```

Comment: I tried...only this works: $("#" + parentDivId).dialog('close');

Comment: @999cm999 This means you have duplicate ID's! Fix that instead!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you might be able to just do:

```
$(div).parent().dialog('close');
```

Comment: unless `div` is actually a div, in which case it would be `$(div).dialog('close')`

Comment: good point! one is (div) and the other is ("div"). so div must be a variable.

Comment: for some reason, only this is working: $("#" + parentDivId).dialog('close');